# Repeat element of a tensor and form a new tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say I have a tensor A=[a1,a2,...], I want to to repeat the element of the tensor and form a new tensor. The number of repetition of each element is indicated in another tensor B. For example if B=[1,3,2,2,..], the result should be [a1,a2,a2,a2,a3,a3,a4,a4,...]. Is there an efficient way to perform this in tensorflow without using loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is copied from this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8246). I am interpreting it because it is interesting and it is without loops. Don't know if it is efficient or not.

If we assume that we want to repeat `[1,2,3]` with `[3,4,5]` repetitions then gist of it is that they create a sparse tensor like this.

> [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

and fill it up like this using `tf.cumsum` cleverly.

> [1. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]

I am interpreting the procedure as much as possible here.

`tf.cumsum([3,4,5]` gives `[ 3  7 12]`

`tf.cumsum([3, 4, 5][:-1])` gives `[3 7]` after removing the last element 12.

`tf.concat([tf.constant([0], dtype=tf.int32), tf.cumsum([3,4,5][:-1])], axis=0)` gives `[0 3 7]`
which are the indices where we see `1`.

> [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

And `1` is obtained using `[1,2,3] - tf.concat([tf.constant([0], dtype=tf.float64), [1,2,3][:-1]], axis=0)`

which is equivalent to subtracting like this. `[1, 2, 3]` - `[0, 1, 2]`. This gives `[1 1 1]` for the values for the sparse indices.

`12` as the output_shape is the total placeholders required in the output which is the reduced cumulative sum of our repeat tensor `[3, 4, 5]`

This gives the final output.

```
print(sess.run(
    tf.cumsum(
    tf.sparse_to_dense(
    sparse_indices=[0, 3, 7],
    output_shape=(12,),
    sparse_values=[1, 1, 1]))))
```